# WPF ICommands Binding

Tags: wpf, icommand

I am continuing my exploration of WPF and trying to follow MVVM with Commands.
My simple code is as follow.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ClickCommand.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClickCommand"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ClickCommand.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ButtonViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Height="80" FontSize="32" Background="LightBlue" Content="Click Me"
                    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxTest" Margin="5" FontSize="36"/>
            <Button Height="80" FontSize="32" Background="LightBlue" Content="Click if TextBox as Text"
                    Command="{Binding ButtonParameterCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBoxTest}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ButtonViewModel.cs

```
public ButtonViewModel()
{
    ButtonCommand = new ButtonCommand();
    ButtonParameterCommand = new ButtonParameterCommand();
}

public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; }
public ICommand ButtonParameterCommand { get; }
```

CommandBase.cs

```
abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);

    protected void OnCanExecutedChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs()); 
    }
}
```

ButtonCommand.cs

```
public override void Execute(object parameter)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button is Clicked");
}
```

ButtonParameterCommand.cs

```
public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
     return true;
}
public override void Execute(object parameter)
{
    MessageBox.Show(parameter as string);
}
```

My issue is I would like to disable the second button if the textbox above IsNullOrEmpty however the code I thought would address this leaves the button permanently disabled. The code I have been trying is `

```
public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
      if (parameter != null)
      {
          if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter as string))
          {
              return false;
          }
          else
          {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Is my error in this or the Xaml Binding? I hope someone can help and thank you in advance for your assistance.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event of the command whenever the text in the `TextBox` changes.

Make the `OnCanExecutedChanged()` method of the `CommandBase` class `public` and call it from the setter of a source property that you bind the `TextBox` to:

```
public class ButtonViewModel
{
    public ButtonViewModel()
    {
        ButtonCommand = new ButtonCommand();
        ButtonParameterCommand = new ButtonParameterCommand();
    }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set 
        { 
            _text = value;
            ButtonParameterCommand.OnCanExecutedChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; }
    public CommandBase ButtonParameterCommand { get; }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxTest" Margin="5" FontSize="36"
         Text="{Binding Text, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"/>
```

But you should really look in to how to implement a "relay" or "delegate" command that accepts an `Action<object>` and a `Predicate<object>` and invoke these in the implementations of the `Execute` and `CanExecute` methods respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your response it is much appreciated. Now I have some working code my next job will be to amend it to utilise a 'Relay Command'. I have introduced into the TextBox xaml code "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" but for some reason the button remains inactive untill 2 chars are added and does not deactivate on removal of all char. Any ideas?

Comment: Still unsure why I have the error using "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" with my code above, but have I have now implemented your suggestion on 'Relay Command' and everything working perfectly. Thanks again